# How to specify lib.a in Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm trying to use [GLC library](http://www.glc-lib.net/) in Visual C++. I download already built version. The library(libGLC_lib2.a) is in ar format. I tried to add libGLC_lib2 or libGLC or libGLC_lib2.a in Visual C++ project properties, but linker gives unresolved external symbols: can't find the library. So is it possible to specify libraries with ar format in Visual Studio?

P.S. The examples within library are Qt based and the library specified with the option -lGLC_lib2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual C++ doesn't use `.a` files for providing the definitions of DLLs, typically it uses `.lib` files. The library linking convention you referenced (`-lGLC_lib2`) is more consistent with GCC command-line arguments, which would explain why the pre-built binaries you downloaded had a `.a` file instead of a `.lib`.

In order to use this library with Visual Studio, you'll likely need to rebuild it from source.

Alternatively, you may be able to produce a `.lib` file from the pre-built binaries. see the following article for more information on how this can be done: http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSVC_and_MinGW_DLLs

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the 'Additional Library Directories' in the linker settings as well as adding the library.